# Need to periodically drop and recreate stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, sql-view

Here is my issue.  I'm using SQL Server 2014.  I have an ASP.Net web-application that accepts a string from a user.  That string is passed to a stored procedure (SP), which queries a view, which queries a linked server.  My data-access layer returns a datatable to my business object.  If there IS data - the inputted string is considered valid (it has a match on the linked server).  If there is NO data, the inputted string is considered invalid (there is no match on the linked server).

So simply, here is the path of info:

WebApp - Stored Procedure - View - Linked Server - Table with data

Obviously this path is reversed once the query executes (and the data is passed from the table and ultimately to the web-app).

Here is where it gets weird.  Twice in the last 13 months since the SP was created (today being the second time), no data was returned to the web-app when VALID strings were entered.  To be clear, this SP has ALWAYS worked (other than these two times).  But, once it fails, it NEVER works until it's dropped and recreated.

So, here is what WORKS:

- Querying the linked server, directly, and adding the string to the
  WHERE clause.
- Querying the view, directly, and adding the string to    the WHERE
  clause.

Here is what DOESN'T work:

- Entering the string into the web-app.
- Querying the SP, directly, and passing the string as a parameter.

And the really, really weird part:

BOTH TIMES that this has happened, dropping and recreating the stored procedure solved the problem.  How is it that a SP will work for months, and then just stop working?  And then how come the fix is to drop and recreate the SP?

Firstly, why is this happening?  There are lots of other web-apps that call SPs, that call views, that call the SAME linked server that have never failed.  But twice in a year ONE SP fails without apparent reason - and deleting and recreating it solved the problem?

Please help - this is really confusing...And please let me know if you need more information.

**EDIT**

In response to alroc's comment:

- The script that creates the stored procedure doesn't have anything to
  do with security.  Any user that can access the DB can access the SP.
- I'm the only DBA here, so no one else "should" be changing any
  security or permissions on the DB.  However, if they were doing
  that, I would expect these problems elsewhere, since the web-app
  using the same SQL login (same connection string) that works for
  every single other process - and there are hundreds of them.

**SECOND EDIT**

In response to beercohol's comment:

- The query is not timing out - it returns no results almost instantly.
  The timeout is set to 30 seconds and this isn't coming close to
  approaching that threshold.
- I ran DBCC CheckDB and no errors were found.
- I will try recompiling the SP next time this happens, but why would the execution plan periodically go bad for ONE SP out of hundreds or thousands?

Comment: Does the script that creates the SP also grant any security related to it? If so, is it possible that someone is "fixing" security and in the process revoking something your SP depends upon?

Comment: @alroc I edited my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Two things I would check - 1) Are you sure the query is not timing out when it returns "no data"? 2) Run DBCC CHECKDB to check your database for corruption.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if a bad cached execution plan could cause this... running `sp_recompile 'MyProcName'` will drop any cached plan and cause it to be re-created the next time the proc is executed.

Comment: @beercohol I edited my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: off topic. Let's move that to dba.stackexchange.com - this is much more an administrative issue as a code issue.

Comment: If this would happen, I would run the stored procedure with `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON`, inspect the plan to see for any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved.  Adding `WITH RECOMPILE` has permanently fixed the issue.  I talked to another software developer and he told me that there is a bug within SQL causing cached performance plans to start performing more and more poorly over time.  It still doesn't explain why this only happens to SOME stored procedures and not all - but, regardless, forcing them to recompile upon execution works!

This, however, would not be a viable option for a highly demanded SP, since you don't want to recompile it a gazillion times - but for my purposes it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't experienced the exact scenario you are describing but I have dealt with an instance where a stored procedure would occasionally start running extremely slowly despite insignificant changes to the underlying data. The problem turned out to be a feature of SQL Server called "parameter sniffing". This feature uses the parameters that are passed at the time the procedure is compiled to determine the execution plan which is cached for future calls.

Parameter sniffing can have undesired effects if passing different parameters to the procedure can significantly affect the resulting execution plan. You will often find this with 'search' procedures which take a large number of parameters  of which only a few are used for any given call.

The solution in my case was to disable the parameter sniffing feature by declaring a local variable for each parameter and copying the values. The local variables are then used in place of the parameters for the rest of the procedure. This is enough to prevent the optimiser from using the original parameter values when determining the execution plan.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of parameter sniffing and have heard of similar issues to yours in the past.  I appreciate your response, but this is definitely not the issue.  This SP has one parameter - and the value in no way effects the execution plan or performance, since the linked server isn't indexed on that column.

Comment: Agreed then - it doesn't sound like this is your issue. I don't have any other suggestions but I'll keep this answer here just in case anyone stumbles by the page with an issue that is related.